# CKEDITOR - Select span by its ID or CLASS and get its data attribute value

Tags: jquery, dom, ckeditor

How do you manage the content in CKEditor with jQuery?

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="ckeditor_block">
   <textarea id="editor1">
      <span class="sub" id="sub1" data-time-start="0">Hello </span>
      <span class="sub" id="sub2" data-time-start="2">My </span>
      <span class="sub" id="sub3" data-time-start="6">Name </span>
      <span class="sub" id="sub4" data-time-start="8">Is </span>
      <span class="sub" id="sub5" data-time-start="12">Zoob</span>
   </textarea>                
</div>
```

My JS:

```
var textarea;

$(document).ready(function () {
    textarea = $('#ckeditor_block').find('textarea').attr('id');
    ckeditor_init();
});

function ckeditor_init() {
    CKEDITOR.replace(textarea, {
        language: 'fr',
        allowedContent: true
    });
}
```

The [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zagloo/7hvrxw2c/2/)

Until this point, this works nice.

Now how can I simply, in the CKeditor iframe or whatever, select for example the `span` with the `ID` = `sub3` and after that get its content (here : `Name`) and its attribute `data-time-start` (here : `6`)?

Moreover, in a loop, how can I select each element with the class `sub`>

Something like this, but with method of CKEDITOR:

```
$.each($(CKEditor.getBody()).find(".sub"), function () { // How select SUB class name in CKEDITOR ??
     var d = $(this).attr("data-time-start"); // HOW SELECT FOR EACH 'SUB' HIS data-time-sart attribute in CKEDITOR ??
     $(".st").removeClass("active"); // HOW REMOVE CLASS FOR ALL class 'SUB' in CKEDITOR ??
     $(this).addClass("active"); // HOW ADD CLASS 'active' TO THIS 'SUB' in CKEDITOR ??    
});
```

I tried to get the content like that, but after. How do I do this?

```
 var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[textarea];
 var $dataCkeditor = editor.getData();
```

Comment: solve it on my desktop, try on urself! Tell, if it doent work, we'll find the trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i clone ur project on my desktop, and it work for me! But in Fiddle IT does not work! Be careful! I dont know why, but in fiddle it just dont work, try that:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ckeditor.com/apps/ckeditor/4.0/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ckeditor_block">
    <textarea id="editor1"> <span class="sub" id="sub1" data-time-start="0">Hello </span>
     <span class="sub" id="sub2" data-time-start="2">My </span>
     <span class="sub" id="sub3" data-time-start="6">Name </span>
     <span class="sub" id="sub4" data-time-start="8">Is </span>
     <span class="sub" id="sub5" data-time-start="12">Zoob</span>
    </textarea>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var textarea;
$(document).ready(function () {
    textarea = $('#ckeditor_block').find('textarea').attr('id');
    CKEDITOR.replace(textarea, {
        language: 'fr',
        uiColor: '#9AB8F3',
        allowedContent: true,
        disallowedContent: 'script; *[on*]',
        enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
        toolbar: [
            ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-', 'TextColor', '-', 'RemoveFormat'],
            ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'],
            ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight'],
            ['Find', 'Replace', 'SelectAll'],
            ['Source', '-', 'Maximize', '-', 'Save']
        ]
    });
    function waitInit(){
        var subs = $( CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.window.getFrame().$ ).contents().find('.sub' );
        $.each(subs, function(){
            $this = $(this);
            console.log("value = " + $this.text());
            console.log("time = " + $this.attr('data-time-start'));
        });
    }
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(){ waitInit(); });
});   
</script>
</body></html>
```

It was 2 trouble - first on fiddle, and second - we call function before ckeditor initialize, i cant find callback for init, so input timeout with a little delay, for it, i test it - all works fine!

Comment: `data-*` attributes can be accessed with `$(myObject).data('time-start')`.

Comment: I forget where, but .data does not work, and i always use full 'data-*' in .attr, but thanks for comment (p.s. i think it was at ie8 on VM)

Comment: Thanks for your Help but I know what you post. In fact I'm using CKEDITOR (see my JSFIDDLE). And its different for manage what I want.

Comment: I edited answer, so - ur main trouble - get elemen from ckeditor's iframe, right?

Comment: undefined value .. :(  see the console in this FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/zagloo/7hvrxw2c/5/

Comment: console.log( CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.getById( 'sub1' ) ); try that in ur project (i think fiddle dont let call like this)

Comment: cos object CKEDITOR.instances.editor1 - has method .document, but in fiddle it is undefined

Comment: Console return this error message " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined "

Comment: u try at your project? or on fiddle? It dont work on fiddle for me, but work at my html, i send u now at answer

Comment: Works nice !! thx !! but now way to resolve this without the setTimeOut ??

Comment: CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(){ waitInit(); });  try it except last row with timeout, i tried - it works fine, edited my ans now

Answer (score 0):

Or You simply did the Following thing,

```
var ele = $(editor.editable().$);
$('span',ele).each(function(){
   console.log($(this).text());
   console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
//editor represent your instance in CKEditor
```

-Thank you.