# ckeditor balloonpanel not staying attached to an element when scrolling

Tags: ckeditor

**UPDATE** balloon panels are staying attached in below code. We still have an issue where when we close a balloon panel, and then scroll afterward, the balloon panel that was just closed reappears. Here’s the updated code.

**HERE WAS THE ORIGINAL QUESTION** I am trying to get the ckeditor balloonpanel to stay attached to the element it was initially attached to; currently, when I scroll in the editor, the balloonpanels do not stay in place. The problem is that the balloonpanels shift when the user scrolls in the editor -- they do not remain attached to their initial element they were attached to when I scroll in the editor. Here is the code for the ckeditor plugin. It creates a balloonpanel in a for loop on return of an web service Ajax call and stores the panel in a global array called panels :

```
( function() {
    var arr = new Array();
    var panels = [];

    var saveCmd = {
        readOnly: 1,
        modes: { wysiwyg: 1,source: 1 },

        exec: function( editor ) {
            if ( editor.fire( 'grade_level_score' ) ) {
                var $form = editor.element.$.form;

                /**
                 * Destroys the balloon panel by removing it from DOM and purging
                 * all associated event listeners.
                 */
                    // https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/64749bb245d1e91f6a4ac4e97c9648ec47acda91/plugins/balloonpanel/plugin.js#L743-L745
                var panel;
                while ( ( panel = panels.pop() ) ) {
                    panel.destroy();
                }

                arr = []; // clear the array of user-editable areas
                panels = []; // clear the array of panels

                // https://stackoverflow.com/a/48022658
                var ele = $(editor.editable().$);
                var elementOfClass;
                var i = 1;

                // class "ice-ice-editable" is in a span
                $('span',ele).each(function(){

                    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/35866999
                    var iceIceEditableClass = "ice-ice-editable";
                    var hasClassIceIceEditable = $(this).hasClass(iceIceEditableClass);

                    if( hasClassIceIceEditable ) {
                        console.log($(this).text());
                        console.log($(this).attr('class'));
                        console.log($(this).attr('id'));

                        var userEditable = "user-editable-" + i;

                        // If the specified attribute already exists, only the value is set/changed.
                        this.setAttribute("id","user-editable-" + i);

                        var record1 = { id : userEditable , userEditableArea : $(this).text() };
                        arr.push(record1);

                        i++;
                    }
                });

                var gradeLevelObject = new Object();
                gradeLevelObject.textAreas = arr;


                // var responseGradeLevelScoreWS = gradeLevelScore(gradeLevelObject);

                // BEGIN for testing
               var result = '{"textAreas":[{"id":"user-editable-1","userEditableArea":"[Insert information specific to what is being addressed (a brief description of request(s) and/or concern(s). Specific training resource document for letter writing assistance will be referenced here.]  ","score":22.24,"readingGrade":7,"issues":["asdf","zxcv"]},{"id":"user-editable-2","userEditableArea":"[Insert information specific to what is being addressed (a brief description of request(s) and/or concern(s). Specific training resource document for letter writing assistance will be referenced here.]  ","score":22.24,"readingGrade":0,"issues":[]},{"id":"user-editable-3","userEditableArea":"[Insert information specific to what is being addressed (a brief description of request(s) and/or concern(s). Specific training resource document for letter writing assistance will be referenced here.]  ","score":22.24,"readingGrade":0,"issues":[]},{"id":"user-editable-4","userEditableArea":"[Insert information specific to what is being addressed (a brief description of request(s) and/or concern(s). Specific training resource document for letter writing assistance will be referenced here.]  ","score":22.24,"readingGrade":0,"issues":[]}]}';
               var responseGradeLevelScoreWS = JSON.parse(result);
                // END for testing

                console.log(responseGradeLevelScoreWS);

                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < responseGradeLevelScoreWS.textAreas.length; i++){

                    if ( responseGradeLevelScoreWS.textAreas[i].readingGrade > 6 ) {
                        var j;
                        var issues = '';
                        for (j = 0; j < responseGradeLevelScoreWS.textAreas[i].issues.length; j++) {
                            issues += '<p>' + responseGradeLevelScoreWS.textAreas[i].issues[j]  + '</p>';
                        }

                        panel = new CKEDITOR.ui.balloonPanel( editor, {
                            title: 'Grade: ' + responseGradeLevelScoreWS.textAreas[i].readingGrade + '. Score: ' + responseGradeLevelScoreWS.textAreas[i].score,
                            content: ( (typeof issues === 'undefined' || issues == null) ? 'There are no suggestions in order to descrease the grade level score' : issues ),
                            width: 500,
                            height: 120
                        });

                        var element = editor.document.getById(responseGradeLevelScoreWS.textAreas[i].id);

                        panel.attach( element );

                        panel.registerFocusable(element);
                        panels.push( panel );
                        issues = '';
                    }
                }

                // We'll use throttling for scroll listener to reduce performance impact.
                var scrollListener = CKEDITOR.tools.eventsBuffer( 100, function() {
                    for (i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {

                        panels[i].attach( editor.document.getById( responseGradeLevelScoreWS.textAreas[i].id ), {
                            focusElement: false,
                            show: false
                        } );

                    }
                } );
                editor.window.on( 'scroll', scrollListener.input );

                if ( $form ) {
                    try {

                        //$form.submit();
                    } catch ( e ) {
                        // If there's a button named "submit" then the form.submit
                        // function is masked and can't be called in IE/FF, so we
                        // call the click() method of that button.
                        if ( $form.submit.click )
                            $form.submit.click();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var pluginName = 'grade_level_score';

    // Register a plugin named "save".
    CKEDITOR.plugins.add( pluginName, {
        // jscs:disable maximumLineLength
        lang: 'en,en-au,en-ca,en-gb,es,es-mx', // %REMOVE_LINE_CORE%
        // jscs:enable maximumLineLength
        icons: 'grade_level_score', // %REMOVE_LINE_CORE%
        hidpi: true, // %REMOVE_LINE_CORE%
        init: function( editor ) {
            // Save plugin is for replace mode only.
            if ( editor.elementMode != CKEDITOR.ELEMENT_MODE_REPLACE )
                return;

            var command = editor.addCommand( pluginName, saveCmd );
            command.startDisabled = !( editor.element.$.form );

            editor.ui.addButton && editor.ui.addButton( 'Grade_Level_Score', {
                //label: editor.lang.save.toolbar,
                label: "Grade Level Score",
                command: pluginName,
                toolbar: 'custom,100'
            } );
        }
    } );
} )();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only [Balloon Toolbar](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/balloontoolbar) has built-in functionality for automatic reposition on scroll. [Balloon Panel](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/balloonpanel) itself is a static element. However, it can be easily achieved by attaching `scroll` listener and repositioning visible panels on scroll:

```
// We'll use throttling for scroll listener to reduce performance impact.
var scrollListener = CKEDITOR.tools.eventsBuffer( 100, function() {
  for (i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
    panels[i].attach( editor.document.getById(ids[i]), {
      focusElement: false,
      show: false
    } );
  }
} );
editor.window.on( 'scroll', scrollListener.input );
```

See [this codepen](https://codepen.io/f1ames/pen/OJLOWgQ?editors=1010) for the full code (reusing some parts of your original code).

Comment: we still have an issue where when we close a balloon panel, and then scroll afterward, the balloon panel that was just closed reappears. I tried keeping track of the closed balloon panels in an array, but that does not work. Here’s the code, I have updated the SO question. Would appreciate if you could help out.

Comment: That's true, I have updated the code snippet and codepen to address this issue. Basically, you need `show: false` option to be provided to `attach()` method which prevents balloon panel to reappear if hidden,

Comment: using latest source from https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/tree/master/plugins/balloontoolbar also helped...